# How to use another file instead of home.php

Tags: templates, search

I have an Elegant Estate Theme and I am using Multiple Category Selection to display some posts, the Result Page is displaying the Feature SlideShow on the top, and I want to eliminate this; I want it to work just as Wordpress Search displays the result (without the Feature Slider).

I found out that the Multiple Category Plugin is using `get_bloginfo('url')`, the home page, to display the results. So I want to create another `home.php`, but without the slider; `homesearch.php`, but how can I call this page instead of `home.php`

[This](http://creta.enmty.com) is the page

Answer (score 1):

You could [filter `home_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Filter_Hierarchy), check for the presence whatever `$_GET` var is reliably set for each of those requests, and load a different template for those cases.

```
function wpd_home_template( $home_template = '' ){
    if( isset( $_GET['search_type'] ) ){
        $home_template = locate_template( 'homesearch.php', false );
    }
    return $home_template;
}
add_filter( 'home_template', 'wpd_home_template' );
```

EDIT- fixed incorrect var test.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just create a Page Template which duplicates the home.php functionality and then remove whatever you need to from that?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates